# What are the data testing and training?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I am starting to work on deep learning models and came across a softmax classification from the book "deep learning with python"

When using training and testing data, we split it in train_x, train_y and test_x, test_y. What exactly is X and Y? I am trying to build a binary softmax classifier but I am unsure if the samples from data set 1 should go on the X set and samples of the second classification go on Y.

Or is it test data all data regardless of labeled data and Y a vector with 1 and 0s only?

Hope I have made myself clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Train data is data used to train the model** (the weights of the model are balanced using this), while **test data is used to test the model's performance** *after* it has been trained (using this data does not alter the weights anymore).

Training and test data are of the same nature: they're generally built by randomising all the data and then picking how much of it to use for training and how much for testing (called **training split**).

**X represents the input data**, while **Y is the output**: the model learns to predict Y from X during the training phase, while during the test phase the Y data is used to compare the model's answer and measure their correctness.

Answer (score 0):

**What exactly is X and Y?**

As you mentioned in your question, you are solving a **classification** problem, which are part of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning set of problems. The classical formulation is that you have an input space **X** and a label space **Y** where an element in the input space represents information you have, and an element in the label space would be a class or category. Every observation you have is a pair (x,y) of an input, associated with a label (e.g (x=[1.70cm,15yrs], y=boy) that comes from real-life data. What your algorithm should do is build a function `classifier` from your input space to your label space so that we have a match:

`classifier(x)==y`

for **as many real-life** pairs (the population space) as possible. It is important to note that you will not have access to all real-life pairs, but you would still like this property to hold (i.e. your classifier *generalizes* well).

**What are the data training?**
There are an infinite number of candidate functions that could be your `classifier` function, so how do you find the one that works? We use some of our available data to create it. How do we create the function? Well that depends on the model (it could be, for example, to choose the best function that is linear in `x`).  But in general, an algorithm algorithm takes the training data as input, and out of all the classifiers possible in your model you select the one that has the most matches. The way to aggregate "most matches" can vary, for classification a common way is to minimize cross-entropy loss.

**Testing data**

You don't need testing data to create your classifier, but you need it to verify that it isn't a bad classifier. The reason is that you can easily make a classifier that works great on your training data, but fails in your population space if you aren't careful (this is what is known as overfitting), for example:

```
def dumb_classifier(x):
    if x in X_train:
        return Y_train[X_train.index(x)]
    else return Y_train[random_index]
```

`dumb_classifier` has 100% accuracy on your training set, but it will perform no better than a random guess when you deploy it!
Using your testing dataset on `dumb_classifier` will let you know that it is performing poorly, and therefore you should discard your model and consider a different model (maybe change your loss function by adding a regularizer).